# tracking submissions by registered and anonymous users in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel's pre-build Auth code.  I have another table submissions which  looks like this

```
Schema::create( 'submissions', function( Blueprint $table ) {
    $table->increments( 'id' );
    $table->enum( 'complete', [ 'yes', 'no' ] );
    $table->string( 'formName' );
    $table->timestamps();

    // Reference to User ID but only when submitted by a registered user...
    //$table->integer( 'user_id' )->unsigned();
    //$table->foreign( 'user_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' );

    $table->integer( 'status_id' )->unsigned();
    $table->foreign( 'status_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'status' );
});
```

When a submission is by a registered user I would like to reference that user id, But anonymous submissions are possible and I need some indicator that the submission is by an anonymous user.

should I?

- creating an actual users records for an anon user
- change my user_id foreign key to allow NULL values to indicate the anon user

or is there a better way?

**EDIT: To expand on my use case**

My application is basically a collection of forms( aren't they all ) for users to input and update information.  Most of the forms will be restricted to Authenticated users.  2-5 forms will be available to both authenticated and non-authenticated users.  IF the form submission is done by an Authenticated user I want to indicate to admins who that user is.  If the user was not authenticated then I simply want to indicate to the admin that it was an anonymous submission.  So Anon users wont require any logic, and this will simply be a flag to indicate the source of hte submission to Admins.  That said it sounds like nullable() key on user_id may be the way to go.

Going forward I'm looking at adding tracking so if a submission is made by a user that becomes an authenticated user I can back track and update their submissions to indicate the user.

Thanks

Comment: Creating a single default anonymous use can have other unwanted consequences for your system. i.e. mail, profile pages, links, awards, 'points' all kind of things that we don't know about your system but that might break stuff or have unintended side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the rest of your system.

For instance, projects like phpBB and Shimmie use a real Anon user. But they flag that user as the guest account in some way. I think Shimmie uses a flag in the users table (ie. users.is_guest = 1) and just authenticates every guest as that user for permission masking. phpBB I believe looks for a user with a certain user_type and within a certain group (ie. users.user_type = 2 && users.groups.contains(1)). Again, phpBB authenticates guests as that Anon user.

One easy way to flag that user (assuming you just have the one non-user user) is to forcibly set its PK to 0 or -1. It'd save space in the database, inherently prevent duplicate "guest" users, and provide you an easy way to prevent routes from showing that user (`->where('id', '[1-9][0-9]*')`).

The alternative (not having a real user or group) means that your authorization logic will need to be able to handle an unauthenticated user. Without more information on your authorization logic, it's a bit difficult to advise.

I'd generally prefer using a real user or real group to pass to my authorization logic. It'd keep everything consistent in the code and provide a common interface in the UI for site admins to change guest permissions.

It'd just require a little work to prevent people from accessing that user via routes or from showing up in user listings and the like. It might be helpful to create a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) on your model to filter out non-user users (your guest account, any bot accounts, etc).

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted, Thanks for the information. Based on this information and my use case as expanded above.  I'm simply going to null the user_id field on submissions when Anon.